# a missing sub document turns into a subdocument with undefined values, and schema validation fails

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, graphql-tools

I have a schema.graphqls that looks like this:

```
type House {
  id: ID!
  rooms: Int!
  address: String!
  owner: Owner
}

type Owner: {
     name: String!,
     age: Int!
}
```

and a complementing mongoose schema:

```
export default class House {
    static schema = {
        rooms: Number
        address: String,
        owner: {
            type : {
                name: String,
                age: Number
            },
            required: false
        }
    };
}
```

and I have an object in my mongodb looking like this (notice owner is missing intentionally):

```
ObjectId("xxx") {
  rooms: 3,
  address: "the street"
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve this document, the owner subdocument is missing (which is fine, its not mandatory). 
The mongoose result fills this missing subdocument with undefined attributes,

```
ObjectId("xxx") {
  rooms: 3,
  address: "the street"
  owner : {
     name: undefined
     age: undefined
}
```

which fails the schema validations (since indeed name and age are mandatory, if subdocument exists).

the actual error i'm getting is:

```
Resolve function for "House.owner" returned undefined
```

Could you possibly point me to whatever i'm doing wrong here?

thanks in advance

Comment: What are the actual mongoose schema definitions in your code? This is more likely a problem with how you have defined those than the graphql types.

Comment: thanks Neil, I edited to reflect how my schema.graphqls file looks like.

Comment: That's not what I said. It's the "mongoose schema" which actually controls the part you are saying produces errors and not the graphql types. That's what you need to include in your question.

Comment: right, added as well.

Answer (score 1):

Following a direction from @Neil Lunn, I realised the problem is in the mongoose schema, 
which led me to add `required: false` - which wasn't enough, but after adding also `default: null` voila.

problem solved. error gone.
final mongoose schema, to whom it may be of interest:

```
export default class House {
    static schema = {
        rooms: Number
        address: String,
        owner: {
            type : {
                name: String,
                age: Number
            },
            required: false,
            default: null
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Actually it's just the `required`, which is optional and defaults to `false`